# Why isn't nvm changing the version of Node I'm using?

Tags: node.js, nvm

See below. NVM says that it is switching me to node version 16. But it really isn't.

```
% node -v
v14.21.3

% nvm use 16
Now using node v16.19.1 (npm v6.14.18)

% node -v
v14.21.3

% which node
/opt/homebrew/opt/node@14/bin/node
```

How can I use node version 16?

Comment: Are you running `node -v` in the same shell after running `nvm use 16`?

Comment: Usaid, Yes. The above output is from a single shell window.

Comment: You have installed node sepereatly your node js path proves that, first uninstall nodejs the nvm will take over and can control your node version

Comment: @Sarkar that's what solved me all the issues, thanks a lot. You should propose it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You have installed node separately and your node path has a higher precedence. First uninstall node and reinstall it using nvm.

#### Linux Solution

Start by finding where node is installed using `which -a node`

Delete the path using `rm -rf <path>` and then install node again using `nvm install node`. This install the latest version of node.

##### Pro tip

Set the version you want to use as default by putting `nvm alias default <version>` in your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` depending on which you use. Now everytime the terminal launches you will have the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this situation after upgrading all of my homebrew packages. To fix it you must run

```
brew uninstall nodejs
```

In my case there are other packages such as `fx`, `mongodb-community` and `mongosh` using `node` so I had to remove all of them. After doing that my `nvm` is working again