# Why doesn't the node version switch via nvm to VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, nvm

I am using the latest version of NVM for Windows 1.1.11. My task is to switch the node version for the project inside VS Code.
When I use nvm in the terminal outside of vs code, everything switches correctly. But in the terminal inside vscode, nvm does not change the node version.
It looks like this:

```
$ nvm list
* 18.16.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
16.20.0
16.16.0

$ nvm use 16.16.0
Now using node v16.16.0 (64-bit)

$ node -v
v18.16.0
```

Please give advice

Comment: Perhaps you just need to start a new terminal. Installing and configuring `nvm` applies certain environment variables that won't be updated if your VSCode terminal has been running since before that

Comment: could be a case of path ordering, or of shell hashing. check both of those.

Comment: @starball I get this error if I do nvm debug command
Another Node.js installation is blocking NVM4W installations from running. Please uninstall the conflicting version or update the PATH environment variable to assure "C:\Program Files\nodejs" precedes "C:\Users\gavri\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v18.16.0".
But I'm not sure what I need to do

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. In my case the problem was that the terminal in Visual Studio Code didn't had the permissions to execute nvm and change the version (needed admin permissions). Maybe this is also the case in your setup.

Another problem could be that one of the node versions wasn't installed via nvm and now causing troubles. Deinstalling the node version that was installed without nvm should solve the issue in that case.
(See [Why isn't nvm changing the version of Node I'm using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75725233/why-isnt-nvm-changing-the-version-of-node-im-using))